# Oracle Package or function in invalid state

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor

Trying to create a pl/sql cursor based function to return details from an oracle database.

The relevant table, `MEETING`, has the columns
`MEETING_ID`: number(10), `TIME`: timestamp(4), `TITLE`: varchar(20)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetMeeting
                    (meetingnumber MEETING.MEETING_ID%TYPE)
RETURN VARCHAR
IS
    CURSOR current_meeting(meetingnumber MEETING.MEETING_ID%TYPE)
    IS
        SELECT TITLE, TIME
        FROM MEETING
        WHERE MEETING_ID = meetingnumber;

    r_meeting current_meeting%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN current_meeting(meetingnumber);

    FETCH current_meeting INTO r_meeting;

    IF current_meeting%NOTFOUND THEN
        r_meeting.TITLE := 'UNKNOWN APPOINTMENT';
        END IF;

        CLOSE current_meeting;

        RETURN r_meeting.TITLE;
    END;


SELECT GetMeeting (27) name
FROM MEETING;
```

The function seems to compile okay - but when called throws

> ORA-06575: Package or function GETMEETING is in an invalid state

Comment: Does the function say it compiled successfully, or successfully with warnings? If the latter you can do `show errors` immediately afterwards. You can also do `show errors function getmeeting` later to see why it's invalid. But you're returning a value from `r_meeting` when you might have got `%notfound`, which might be a problem at runtime? Maybe more importantly, declaring the return as `varchar` rather than `varchar2` might be an issue, but I wouldn't have thought so.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with that. With your table definition the function compiles and runs OK. How you're calling it doesn't make sense but I assume that's a test. Updating the `r_meeting` value is unusual maybe but seems to work OK.

Comment: It just says: "function created". attempting to enable show errors; causes the compiler to go bananas "Encountered the symbol "SHOW""

Comment: OK, `show errors` only works in SQL*Plus and SQL Developer as far as I know; you can look in the `user_errors` table instead, but it shouldn't show anything if it said it compiled successfully. Which 'compiler' are you using? (And do you have a `/` between the `end` and the `select` you're using to test it? I was assuming so from the way you've worded it, but it isn't shown...)

Comment: I actually ran the elect statement separately. Terminating the plsql with the / causes compilation failure. 

The compiler is Application Express

Comment: No data found in user_errors table relating to the function, apparently.

Comment: Create the function through SQL*Plus and use show errors there.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will work better for you:

```
create or replace function
  getmeeting(
    meeting_id number)
return
  varchar
is
  meeting_title meeting.title%Type;
begin
  select title
  into   meeting_title
  from   meeting
  where  meeting_id = getmeeting.meeting_id;

  return meeting_title;
exception
  when NO_DATA_FOUND then
     return 'UNKNOWN APPOINTMENT';
end;
/
```

Not syntax checked.

Answer (score 0):

Error being generated by column identifier 'TIME' which is an SQL keyword; triggering a runtime error when executed.

Code unfortunately returns NULL when 'TIME' is removed

Comment: That value isn't being used anyway, so you might as well remove it. This doesn't seem to be an answer to the question, however.

Comment: The question was about the particular error generated by oracle, which is fixed by removing that particular column. Unfortunately your code (surprisingly) throws the same error.

The function still doesn't do anything useful, mind, as for some reason it is returning NULL unless the UNKNOWN APPOINTMENT exception is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't enough facts to know but I would look into some form of circular dependency.

```
select * 
  from user_dependencies 
 where referenced_name = 'GETMEETING' 
   and referenced_type = 'FUNCTION';
```

The best way to avoid circular dependencies is to use packages where references to other packages are made in the body only. Avoid standalone function and procedure objects.